# Standardize Unit of measurements in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Consider I have the following dataframe

```
d = {'quantity': [100, 910, 500, 50, 0.5, 22.5, 1300, 600, 20], 'uom': ['KG', 'GM', 'KG', 'KG', 'GM', 'MT', 'GM', 'GM', 'MT']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

My dataframe is like this:

```
    quantity    uom
0   100.0       KG
1   910.0       GM
2   500.0       KG
3   50.0        KG
4   0.5         GM
5   22.5        MT
6   1300.0      GM
7   600.0       GM
8   20.0        MT
```

Now I want to use a single UOM for all the data. For that I have the following code:

```
listy = []
listy.append(list(df['quantity']))
listy.append(list(df['uom']))

for index, x in enumerate(listy[0]):
    if listy[1][index] == 'MT':
            listy[0][index] = '{:1.4f}'.format(x * 1000)
            listy[1][index] = 'KG'

    elif listy[1][index] == 'LBS':
        listy[0][index] = '{:1.4f}'.format(x * 0.453592)
        listy[1][index] = 'KG'

    elif listy[1][index] == 'GM':
        listy[0][index] = '{:1.4f}'.format(x * 0.001)
        listy[1][index] = 'KG'

    elif listy[1][index] == 'MG':
        listy[0][index] = '{:1.4f}'.format(x * 0.000001)
        listy[1][index] = 'KG'

    elif listy[1][index] == 'KG':
        listy[0][index] = '{:1.4f}'.format(x * 1)
        listy[1][index] = 'KG'

df['quantity'] = listy[0]
df['uom'] = listy[1]
df

    quantity    uom
0   100.0000    KG
1   0.9100      KG
2   500.0000    KG
3   50.0000     KG
4   0.0005      KG
5   22500.0000  KG
6   1.3000      KG
7   0.6000      KG
8   20000.0000  KG
```

But If we have a really large dataframe I dont think looping through it would be a good way of doing this.

Can I do the similar in some better way?
I was also trying List Comprehension but couldn't do it using that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map using a `dict` and `multiply` the values i.e

```
vals = {'MT':1000, 'LBS':0.453592, 'GM':  0.001, 'MG':0.000001, 'KG':1}

df['new'] = df['quantity']*df['uom'].map(vals)

  quantity uom         new
0     100.0  KG    100.0000
1     910.0  GM      0.9100
2     500.0  KG    500.0000
3      50.0  KG     50.0000
4       0.5  GM      0.0005
5      22.5  MT  22500.0000
6    1300.0  GM      1.3000
7     600.0  GM      0.6000
8      20.0  MT  20000.0000
```

If you want to add 'KG' as a column values then use `df['new_unit'] = 'KG'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on rows by specifying the `axis` parameter. Like this:

```
uom_map = {
    'KG': 1,
    'GM': .001,
    'MT': 1000,
    'LBS': 0.453592,
    'MG': .000001,
}    

def to_kg(row):
    quantity, uom = row.quantity, row.uom
    multiplier = uom_map[uom]
    return quantity*multiplier

df['quantity_kg'] = df.apply(to_kg, axis=1)
```